# ld finds library when run stand along but cant find when building executable

Tags: linker, linker-errors, persistent-storage

I am trying to build a program that requires the linking of libndctl. However, ld fails to find the library, and the build errors out at the linking stage stating (this used to build without error some time before):

Command:

```
g++ tatp_db.cc tatp_nvm.cc ../include/txopt.cc -lpmem -lpthread  -o tatp_nvm -std=c++11 -static
```

Error:

```
  /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpmem.a(libpmem_all.o): in function `pmem2_device_dax_alignment':
memset_t_avx512f.c:(.text+0xb527): undefined reference to `ndctl_new'
/usr/bin/ld: memset_t_avx512f.c:(.text+0xb59e): undefined reference to `ndctl_namespace_get_dax'
/usr/bin/ld: memset_t_avx512f.c:(.text+0xb5b5): undefined reference to `ndctl_dax_get_align'
/usr/bin/ld: memset_t_avx512f.c:(.text+0xb5ce): undefined reference to `ndctl_unref'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpmem.a(libpmem_all.o): in function `pmem2_device_dax_size':
memset_t_avx512f.c:(.text+0xb62f): undefined reference to `ndctl_new'
/usr/bin/ld: memset_t_avx512f.c:(.text+0xb6a9): undefined reference to `ndctl_namespace_get_dax'
/usr/bin/ld: memset_t_avx512f.c:(.text+0xb6c0): undefined reference to `ndctl_dax_get_size'
/usr/bin/ld: memset_t_avx512f.c:(.text+0xb700): undefined reference to `ndctl_unref'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpmem.a(libpmem_all.o): in function `pmem2_region_namespace':
memset_t_avx512f.c:(.text+0xc3ab): undefined reference to `ndctl_bus_get_first'
/usr/bin/ld: memset_t_avx512f.c:(.text+0xc3c0): undefined reference to `ndctl_region_get_first'
/usr/bin/ld: memset_t_avx512f.c:(.text+0xc3d5): undefined reference to `ndctl_namespace_get_first'
/usr/bin/ld: memset_t_avx512f.c:(.text+0xc3f2): undefined reference to `ndctl_namespace_get_dax'
/usr/bin/ld: memset_t_avx512f.c:(.text+0xc41e): undefined reference to `ndctl_dax_get_daxctl_region'
/usr/bin/ld: memset_t_avx512f.c:(.text+0xc463): undefined reference to `daxctl_dev_get_first'
/usr/bin/ld: memset_t_avx512f.c:(.text+0xc475): undefined reference to `daxctl_dev_get_devname'
/usr/bin/ld: memset_t_avx512f.c:(.text+0xc4e1): undefined reference to `daxctl_dev_get_next'
/usr/bin/ld: memset_t_avx512f.c:(.text+0xc512): undefined reference to `ndctl_namespace_get_btt'
/usr/bin/ld: memset_t_avx512f.c:(.text+0xc529): undefined reference to `ndctl_btt_get_block_device'
/usr/bin/ld: memset_t_avx512f.c:(.text+0xc53b): undefined reference to `ndctl_namespace_get_pfn'
/usr/bin/ld: memset_t_avx512f.c:(.text+0xc552): undefined reference to `ndctl_pfn_get_block_device'
/usr/bin/ld: memset_t_avx512f.c:(.text+0xc564): undefined reference to `ndctl_namespace_get_block_device'
/usr/bin/ld: memset_t_avx512f.c:(.text+0xc5d1): undefined reference to `ndctl_namespace_get_next'
/usr/bin/ld: memset_t_avx512f.c:(.text+0xc5ec): undefined reference to `ndctl_region_get_next'
/usr/bin/ld: memset_t_avx512f.c:(.text+0xc607): undefined reference to `ndctl_bus_get_next'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpmem.a(libpmem_all.o): in function `pmem2_get_region_id':
memset_t_avx512f.c:(.text+0xc64f): undefined reference to `ndctl_new'
/usr/bin/ld: memset_t_avx512f.c:(.text+0xc6f8): undefined reference to `ndctl_region_get_id'
/usr/bin/ld: memset_t_avx512f.c:(.text+0xc70a): undefined reference to `ndctl_unref'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:9: all] Error 1
```

I tried fixing this by manually adding -lndctl to the build command

```
g++ tatp_db.cc tatp_nvm.cc ../include/txopt.cc -lpmem -lpthread -lndctl -o tatp_nvm -std=c++11 -static
```

Error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lndctl
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:9: all] Error 1
```

I see that the library exists in /usr/lib/ and when running ld stand-alone (/usr/bin/ld  -lndctl --verbose) it finds the library. Does anyone know what causes this to happen and a fix?

Comment: First of all, please don't tag multiple language tags. Only the one you're actually program in. Secondly, since it seems you're using `make` to build your program, then it should be possible to see the actual command being executed. Please [edit] your question to include the full linker command and all its options and flags (and compare to your own when you link yourself and make it work).

Comment: What do you mean by stand-alone? Calling it without anything to link? Then it doesn't 
*need* the library, so doesn't care for at all... The error list rather looks like you forgot to tell the linker to *use* that library...

Comment: "*when running ld stand-alone*". I assume you mean you run `ld` command directly to link the executable. Well then compare the `ld` command you run directly with what `make` is running. If that is not what you mean then please clarify what that statement means.

Comment: The message mentions that functions are not found. It does not mention that a specified lib is not found. Did you add the lib to your link options?

Answer (score 0):

> Command:
> `g++ tatp_db.cc tatp_nvm.cc ../include/txopt.cc -lpmem -lpthread  -o tatp_nvm -std=c++11 -static`

That command is *wrong*: you said yourself that this binary requires `libndtcl`, yet you aren't listing that library on the command line, so *of course* its symbols end up being unresolved.

> I tried fixing this by manually adding -lndctl to the build command

That is the *correct* fix.

> `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lndctl`
> I see that the library exists in /usr/lib/

There are a few likely root causes:

1. If you are linking a 64-bit executable (which seems likely), `/usr/lib/libndctl*` may exist, but is a 32-bit binary.
   You need a 64-bit version (usually found in `/usr/lib64`) and *that version* is not present.
2. You have *only* `libndctl.so*`, but not `libndtcl.a` (the latter is *required* for `-static` link).
   To fix, you would need to install `libndctl-dev` or similar package.